# handle error of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following error is occurring in my web page on browser

```
script may be busy or not responding
```

I want to avoid it from occurring so how can i do it,

please give me a solution about that

Comment: please provide more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop probably is an infinite loop. The condition you are using will always be true, then it will never finish an cause the error.